# how to deploy a node app to hostinger vps

Tags: node.js, hosting, web-deployment

I want to deploy a node app to a hostinger vps server but I cant find any tutorial on how to do that , the only thing I found was how to setup your vps server to work with node but not on deployment.
I used to use heroku for my node apps and its very simple .
but I have read that hostinger vps can be used to run node , so if anyone deployed a node app to hostinger before ; please tell me how to do so or give me any useful reference or tutorial that can help me

Answer (score 0):

For deploying node.js app I can recommend PM2 process manager, it's easier to use after installation.